# Compare two Sharepoint lists and send email

Tags: power-automate

I have two Sharepoint lists. List A is the master list, with all the IDs. (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9).  This list also includes a column (single line of text) that can have a single or multiple email addresses, separated by semicolon.

List B have  list could look something like this (1,2,2,3,4,5,6,7).

I need a flow that compares the IDs from List B to the IDs in List A, and then sends an unique email from multiple email address for each ID that isn't in List B, using the email contact column values from List A.

I am very new, so feel free to dumb your answer down as much as you have time to do so.  I think that if I can solve this one last step, I can fully automate a manual process.I very much appreciate your help.

[List A]

[image]

[List B]

[image]

to: bof777@email.com
body-Title
1

3

4

to:bof111@email.com
body-Title

2

5

Comment: How often do you want to run this flow? How large are your lists (roughly)?

Answer (score 1):

You could use (if these aren't large lists) a Filter array action for this. Compare the two arrays of unique ids with each other in that action.

Damien Bird has a nice blog about this approach (Except section of that blog):
https://www.damobird365.com/efficien-union-except-and-intersect-great-method/